# How can I make an iterator over fields of container's items?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, iterator

So, say, I have a class that has `std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>>` inside of it; how can I implement an iterator for this class such that it iterates over strings contained in this list?

Or, for example, in my class I have a vector of `struct`s with fields `a`, `b` and `c`; can I create an iterator (maybe inherit vector's iterator? don't know), which, when dereferenced, will return a `std::pair`, corresponding to `(b, c)`?

By iterator I mean something like `std::vector`'s iterators: something, that I can get via `whatever.begin()` and iterate over, as mentioned, strings inside the list.

**UPD** Okay, here's more info on what I want. In my `HashMap` class I have `items`: a list of `structs`: each with a key, a value and a pointer to it's place in the table. What I need is an iterator; but not the one that I can get by doing `items.begin()`, since this iterator, when dereferenced, will return my struct. I need an iterator, such that I can return it when user calls `HashMap.begin()`, and it should dereference into a `std::pair`, corresponding to (key, value).

This should, hopefully, make my question clearer.

**UPD2** 
Here is my `struct`, if that helps:

```
template<class KeyType, class ValueType>
struct node {
    KeyType key;
    ValueType value;
    node** place;

    node(KeyType key_ = KeyType(), ValueType value_ = ValueType()): key(key_), value(value_) {};
};
```

Comment: You cannot for arbitrary struct defnitions. That would require runtime reflection, which isn't available in c++. You can provide your own iterator implementation doing so for each concrete struct where you'll need to use that though. May be [`std::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) is useful when doing so.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the strings in your list or something else?

Comment: You should explain **why** you need such iterators because there may alternative ways of doing it.

Comment: @Galik precisely, yes

Comment: @Akiiino The `std::list` comes with its own iterator.

Comment: @Holt because I have been given a task to write a HashMap class, complete with iterators and everything. I understand the algorithmic part of this, but I couldn't figure out how the hell to work with iterators; hence my question

Comment: @Galik as you could have noticed, the list I mention as an example is not a list of strings, so that's not quite that obvious

Comment: But you can still access the `std::string` instances in the list using the list iterator and doing the operation `it->second`, unless I'm completely misunderstanding the question

Comment: It would be easier to help if you can give the definition of your `struct`.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon I've added it to my question

Answer (score 2):

One elegant way is to use transforming iterators or a transformed range:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

int main() {
    std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>> l;
    auto extractor = [](auto&& elem) { return elem.second; };

    // Using a transformed range.
    for(auto&& v: l | boost::adaptors::transformed(extractor))
        std::cout << v << '\n';

    // Using transform iterators.
    for(auto i = boost::make_transform_iterator(l.begin(), extractor), j = boost::make_transform_iterator(l.end(), extractor); i != j; ++i)
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
}
```

To use a transform iterator for you containers you can do something like:

```
struct MyContianer
{
    std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>> container;

    static auto constexpr first_extractor = [](auto&& elem) { return elem.second; };
    using iterator_first = decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator(container.begin(), first_extractor));
    iterator_first begin_first() { return {container.begin(), first_extractor}; }
    iterator_first end_first() { return {container.end(), first_extractor}; }

    static auto constexpr second_extractor = [](auto&& elem) { return elem.second; };
    using iterator_second = decltype(boost::make_transform_iterator(container.begin(), second_extractor));
    iterator_second begin_second() { return {container.begin(), second_extractor}; }
    iterator_second end_second() { return {container.end(), second_extractor}; }

};
decltype(MyContianer::first_extractor) constexpr MyContianer::first_extractor;
decltype(MyContianer::second_extractor) constexpr MyContianer::second_extractor;

int main() {
    MyContianer c;
    c.begin_first();
    c.begin_second();
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure I'm not allowed to use `boost` and such, so... While this  is great, that does not help me

Comment: @Akiiino If you cannot reuse boost, you can reuse the underlying ideas: make an iterator class template for your container, one template parameter is the transform function / extractor object type.